# google apps script message loop error on split

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, web-scraping, split

I've got this script that works (I get the outputs I expect) but then gives me a Cannot call method "split of undefined (line 16). If I comment out line 16, the error moves to line 17 etc.

```
function emf()
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('####').getSheetByName('EMF');
{
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("tkh_emf");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      var fullname = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("Name*: ")[1].split("\n")[0]; // used for GMap column title
      var fname = fullname.split(" ")[0];
      var lname = fullname.split(" ")[1];
      var email = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("Email*: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
      var phone = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("Phone*: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
      var addr = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("Street Address*: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
      var city = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("City*: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
      var find = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("hear about us?*: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
      var referrer = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("Referrer Name: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
      var photo = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("(max size 2MB): ")[1].split("\n")[0];
      var site = messages[j].getSubject().split("Contact ")[1].split("from")[0];
      var date = messages[j].getDate();
      var work = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("Brief description of work requested*: ")[1].split("Visitor IP: ")[0];
      var ip = messages[j].getPlainBody().split("Visitor IP: ")[1].split("Follow @emfteam")[0];

      // var rowNum = lastRow + 1;
      ss.appendRow([fullname, fname, lname, date, work, photo, email, phone, addr, city, find, referrer, site, ip,'pending','pending']);      
    }
      // threads[i].removeLabel(label);
  }
}
```

Here's the format of all the messages that I am scraping ... 
[image]

What am I missing? Why is it giving me an error?

Comment: Add the line `Logger.log(messages[j]);` in front of `var fullname = ...`. Run the code and then look at the log by pressing ctrl+enter. You could also add the line `if(!messages[j].getPlainBody()) continue;` to make it skip all mails it can't get a plain body for.

Comment: It's checking 5 messages instead of the expected 4 but I only have 4 messages with that label ... if I change `i<threads.length` to `i<threads.length-1` then it only checks 3 messages instead of the expected 4 ...?

Comment: I'm guessing one of those 5 messages is not a real email but something else. Just skip that one e.g. with continue as I already explained.

Comment: Ah ... found a message in the trash with that label. Got rid of it and it works fine. Where in the code does `if(!messages[j].getPlainBody()) continue;' go? Wherever I put it, I still got the error when the message in the trash was still labeled.

Comment: Right in front of `var fullname = ...`

Comment: Weird .. that's were I put it but it still gave me the error. The message is permanently deleted now so can't retest .

Comment: There is another way to skip the non working messages by using `try` and `catch`. I posted an answer that demonstrates this.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip any messages that cause an error with `try` and `catch`. Here is an example

```
function emf()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('####').getSheetByName('EMF');
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("tkh_emf");
  var threads = label.getThreads();

  for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++)
  {
    var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
    for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++)
    {
      try {
        var plainBody = messages[j].getPlainBody();
        var fullname = plainBody.split("Name*: ")[1].split("\n")[0]; // used for GMap column title
        var fname = fullname.split(" ")[0];
        var lname = fullname.split(" ")[1];
        var email = plainBody.split("Email*: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
        var phone = plainBody.split("Phone*: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
        var addr = plainBody.split("Street Address*: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
        var city = plainBody.split("City*: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
        var find = plainBody.split("hear about us?*: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
        var referrer = plainBody.split("Referrer Name: ")[1].split("\n")[0];
        var photo = plainBody.split("(max size 2MB): ")[1].split("\n")[0];
        var site = messages[j].getSubject().split("Contact ")[1].split("from")[0];
        var date = messages[j].getDate();
        var work = plainBody.split("Brief description of work requested*: ")[1].split("Visitor IP: ")[0];
        var ip = plainBody.split("Visitor IP: ")[1].split("Follow @emfteam")[0];

        ss.appendRow([fullname, fname, lname, date, work, photo, email, phone, addr, city, find, referrer, site, ip,'pending','pending']);      
      } catch(e) {
      }
    }
  }
}
```